# How to Send Group Sms?

Tags: java-me, sms

Can we send SMS programatically by selecting group from the address book using J2me?

Answer (score 0):

yes... it is possible to have access to the users phonebook (if supported on the device(most modern devices do allow it)) via PIM(JSR 75).
And sending SMS's from j2me is also possible(again if the user allows this).

Comment: yes i know i can access the phone book as well send sms BUT I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO ADD/Select CONTACT GROUP FROM ADDRESS BOOK using j2me?

Comment: MY HUMBLEST APOLOGIES SIR FOR MISINTERPRETING YOUR LUCID QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can only send a single message to a single recipient at a time using [JSR-205](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205).

If you want to send the same message to many recipients, you have to loop around

`javax.wireless.messaging.Message.setAddress();
javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection.send();`

There is no way to add a `javax.microedition.pim.ContactList` to a `Message` or to a `MessageConnection` because there can't be any API dependancy between JSR-205 and [JSR-75](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75).

The latest [JavaME SDK](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp) contains example code that shows how to read contact data in a MIDlet.